# Jhipster upgrade failing

Tags: upgrade, jhipster

I did a manual upgrade to the latest jhipster version all according to the release notes, without upgrading my entities at first.

- delete node_modules folder
- yarn global upgrade generator-jhipster
- jhipster

, and I let 'jhipster' overwrite everything.
When i ran ./gradlew I got 7 compile errors in the files

```
config/JacksonConfiguration
config/SecurityConfiguration
```

I seems to be a dependency issue. It can't find:

```
import io.github.jhipster.config.JHipsterProperties;
import io.github.jhipster.security.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.hibernate5.Hibernate5Module;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.afterburner.AfterburnerModule;
```

What did I do wrong ?

The output from compiler as follows:

```
amfibia@x53s-mint ~/projects/colony $ ./gradlew

> Task :compileJava
/home/amfibia/projects/colony/src/main/java/net/amfibia/colony/config/SecurityConfiguration.java:67: error: reference to AjaxAuthenticationSuccessHandler is ambiguous
    public AjaxAuthenticationSuccessHandler ajaxAuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
           ^
  both class io.github.jhipster.security.AjaxAuthenticationSuccessHandler in io.github.jhipster.security and class net.amfibia.colony.security.AjaxAuthenticationSuccessHandler in net.amfibia.colony.security match
/home/amfibia/projects/colony/src/main/java/net/amfibia/colony/config/SecurityConfiguration.java:72: error: reference to AjaxAuthenticationFailureHandler is ambiguous
    public AjaxAuthenticationFailureHandler ajaxAuthenticationFailureHandler() {
           ^
  both class io.github.jhipster.security.AjaxAuthenticationFailureHandler in io.github.jhipster.security and class net.amfibia.colony.security.AjaxAuthenticationFailureHandler in net.amfibia.colony.security match
/home/amfibia/projects/colony/src/main/java/net/amfibia/colony/config/SecurityConfiguration.java:77: error: reference to AjaxLogoutSuccessHandler is ambiguous
    public AjaxLogoutSuccessHandler ajaxLogoutSuccessHandler() {
           ^
  both class io.github.jhipster.security.AjaxLogoutSuccessHandler in io.github.jhipster.security and class net.amfibia.colony.security.AjaxLogoutSuccessHandler in net.amfibia.colony.security match
/home/amfibia/projects/colony/src/main/java/net/amfibia/colony/config/SecurityConfiguration.java:82: error: reference to Http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint is ambiguous
    public Http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint() {
           ^
  both class io.github.jhipster.security.Http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint in io.github.jhipster.security and class net.amfibia.colony.security.Http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint in net.amfibia.colony.security match
/home/amfibia/projects/colony/src/main/java/net/amfibia/colony/config/apidoc/SwaggerConfiguration.java:32: error: cannot find symbol
@Profile(Constants.SPRING_PROFILE_SWAGGER)
                  ^
  symbol:   variable SPRING_PROFILE_SWAGGER
  location: class Constants
/home/amfibia/projects/colony/src/main/java/net/amfibia/colony/config/apidoc/PageableParameterBuilderPlugin.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
@Profile(Constants.SPRING_PROFILE_SWAGGER)
                  ^
  symbol:   variable SPRING_PROFILE_SWAGGER
  location: class Constants
/home/amfibia/projects/colony/src/main/java/net/amfibia/colony/config/HerokuDatabaseConfiguration.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
@Profile(Constants.SPRING_PROFILE_HEROKU)
                  ^
  symbol:   variable SPRING_PROFILE_HEROKU
  location: class Constants
7 errors


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED in 3s
```

Comment: You should ask an actual question.

Answer (score 0):

Both `io.github.jhipster.security.AjaxAuthenticationFailureHandler`  and `net.amfibia.colony.security.AjaxAuthenticationFailureHandler` provides the same bean while your configuration expects only one. It just means that this class was generated in the version of Jhipster you initially used and now they are part of [jhipster lib](http://jhipster/jhipster).

Just delete the generated class `net.amfibia.colony.security.AjaxAuthenticationFailureHandler` as it's no longer required as long as you haven't customized it.

Same for others.

This kind of issue is well covered by the automatic `jhipster upgrade` command because it uses branches to compare generation by old version and by new version then merges with your customizations.

Comment: Thanks  Gaël, Iøm almost there now.

Answer (score 0):

If your projet is under Git, do `git reset --hard HEAD` ; `git clean -f -d`  to reset all you have done manually and run `jhipster upgrade` for automatic upgrade.

Comment: I am upgrading from 3.10 to 4.6.2  - the upgrade kit does not work. That why I made a manual update, but has also problems it seems.

Answer (score 0):

When I make a new project with version 4.6.2 , everything is ok, I can run it with ./gradlew
But when upgrading manually, according to the guide, Gradle ends up with some dependency issues.

This line was missing from gradle:
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch"
, when comparing with the new Project sample. It compiles now, but something else is wrong because I get runtime errors:

Can anyone see what is going on ?

```
 ./gradlew

> Task :bootRun
Ignoring Class-Path entry lib/snakeyaml-1.13.jar found in/home/amfibia/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.liquibase/liquibase-core/3.5.3/f346404c3876c5bd0e07a7e10b7565bdcd35dbab/liquibase-core-3.5.3.jar as /home/amfibia/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.liquibase/liquibase-core/3.5.3/f346404c3876c5bd0e07a7e10b7565bdcd35dbab/lib/snakeyaml-1.13.jar does not exist
13:50:22.175 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Included patterns for restart : []
13:50:22.180 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Excluded patterns for restart : [/spring-boot-starter/target/classes/, /spring-boot-autoconfigure/target/classes/, /spring-boot-starter-[\w-]+/, /spring-boot/target/classes/, /spring-boot-actuator/target/classes/, /spring-boot-devtools/target/classes/]
13:50:22.181 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls - Matching URLs for reloading : [file:/home/amfibia/projects/colony/build/classes/java/main/, file:/home/amfibia/projects/colony/build/resources/main/]

        ██╗ ██╗   ██╗ ████████╗ ███████╗   ██████╗ ████████╗ ████████╗ ███████╗
        ██║ ██║   ██║ ╚══██╔══╝ ██╔═══██╗ ██╔════╝ ╚══██╔══╝ ██╔═════╝ ██╔═══██╗
        ██║ ████████║    ██║    ███████╔╝ ╚█████╗     ██║    ██████╗   ███████╔╝
  ██╗   ██║ ██╔═══██║    ██║    ██╔════╝   ╚═══██╗    ██║    ██╔═══╝   ██╔══██║
  ╚██████╔╝ ██║   ██║ ████████╗ ██║       ██████╔╝    ██║    ████████╗ ██║  ╚██╗
   ╚═════╝  ╚═╝   ╚═╝ ╚═══════╝ ╚═╝       ╚═════╝     ╚═╝    ╚═══════╝ ╚═╝   ╚═╝

:: JHipster   :: Running Spring Boot 1.5.4.RELEASE ::
:: https://jhipster.github.io ::

2017-07-31 13:50:23.399  INFO 6678 --- [  restartedMain] net.amfibia.colony.ColonyApp             : Starting ColonyApp on x53s-mint with PID 6678 (/home/amfibia/projects/colony/build/classes/java/main started by amfibia in /home/amfibia/projects/colony)
2017-07-31 13:50:23.400 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] net.amfibia.colony.ColonyApp             : Running with Spring Boot v1.5.4.RELEASE, Spring v4.3.9.RELEASE
2017-07-31 13:50:23.401  INFO 6678 --- [  restartedMain] net.amfibia.colony.ColonyApp             : The following profiles are active: swagger,dev
2017-07-31 13:50:23.725 DEBUG 6678 --- [kground-preinit] org.jboss.logging                        : Logging Provider: org.jboss.logging.Slf4jLoggerProvider found via system property
2017-07-31 13:50:27.871 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] n.a.colony.config.AsyncConfiguration     : Creating Async Task Executor
2017-07-31 13:50:29.055 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.amfibia.colony.domain.User       : Initialize successful.
2017-07-31 13:50:29.071 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.amfibia.colony.domain.Authority  : Initialize successful.
2017-07-31 13:50:29.077 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.a.c.domain.User.authorities      : Initialize successful.
2017-07-31 13:50:29.083 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.a.colony.domain.PersistentToken  : Initialize successful.
2017-07-31 13:50:29.087 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.a.c.d.User.persistentTokens      : Initialize successful.
2017-07-31 13:50:29.094 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.a.c.domain.SocialUserConnection  : Initialize successful.
2017-07-31 13:50:29.101 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.amfibia.colony.domain.Contact    : Initialize successful.
2017-07-31 13:50:29.108 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.amfibia.colony.domain.Colony     : Initialize successful.
2017-07-31 13:50:29.113 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.a.c.domain.Colony.residences     : Initialize successful.
2017-07-31 13:50:29.118 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.a.c.domain.Colony.residenceTags  : Initialize successful.
2017-07-31 13:50:29.123 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.amfibia.colony.domain.Residence  : Initialize successful.
2017-07-31 13:50:29.127 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.a.c.d.Residence.residenceTags    : Initialize successful.
2017-07-31 13:50:29.131 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.a.colony.domain.ResidenceTag     : Initialize successful.
2017-07-31 13:50:29.135 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.a.c.d.ResidenceTag.residences    : Initialize successful.
2017-07-31 13:50:29.138 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.a.c.domain.AccountingAccount     : Initialize successful.
2017-07-31 13:50:29.140 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.a.c.d.AccountingAccount.entries  : Initialize successful.
2017-07-31 13:50:29.143 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.a.colony.domain.AccountingEntry  : Initialize successful.
2017-07-31 13:50:29.145 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.a.colony.domain.AccountDetails   : Initialize successful.
2017-07-31 13:50:29.148 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.a.c.d.AccountingTransaction      : Initialize successful.
2017-07-31 13:50:29.151 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.a.c.d.A.entries                  : Initialize successful.
2017-07-31 13:50:29.154 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.amfibia.colony.domain.Ledger     : Initialize successful.
2017-07-31 13:50:29.156 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.a.c.d.Ledger.accountingAccounts  : Initialize successful.
2017-07-31 13:50:29.159 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.a.c.domain.Ledger.transactions   : Initialize successful.
2017-07-31 13:50:29.161 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.amfibia.colony.domain.Invoice    : Initialize successful.
2017-07-31 13:50:29.163 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.a.c.domain.Invoice.payments      : Initialize successful.
2017-07-31 13:50:29.166 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.a.c.d.I.invoiceCreditNotes       : Initialize successful.
2017-07-31 13:50:29.168 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.amfibia.colony.domain.Product    : Initialize successful.
2017-07-31 13:50:29.171 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.amfibia.colony.domain.Payment    : Initialize successful.
2017-07-31 13:50:29.173 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.a.colony.domain.BankAccount      : Initialize successful.
2017-07-31 13:50:29.175 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.a.c.domain.PaymentConditions     : Initialize successful.
2017-07-31 13:50:29.178 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.amfibia.colony.domain.Purchase   : Initialize successful.
2017-07-31 13:50:29.182 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.a.colony.domain.SubAccountTag    : Initialize successful.
2017-07-31 13:50:29.186 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.a.c.domain.PurchaseCreditNote    : Initialize successful.
2017-07-31 13:50:29.189 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.a.c.domain.InvoiceCreditNote     : Initialize successful.
2017-07-31 13:50:29.193 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.a.colony.domain.BalanceOut       : Initialize successful.
2017-07-31 13:50:29.196 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.a.colony.domain.Notification     : Initialize successful.
2017-07-31 13:50:29.198 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.a.colony.domain.FundsTransfer    : Initialize successful.
2017-07-31 13:50:29.622 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] n.a.colony.config.MetricsConfiguration   : Registering JVM gauges
2017-07-31 13:50:29.641 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] n.a.colony.config.MetricsConfiguration   : Monitoring the datasource
2017-07-31 13:50:29.641 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] n.a.colony.config.MetricsConfiguration   : Initializing Metrics JMX reporting
2017-07-31 13:50:30.570 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] net.amfibia.colony.config.WebConfigurer  : Registering CORS filter
2017-07-31 13:50:30.800  INFO 6678 --- [  restartedMain] net.amfibia.colony.config.WebConfigurer  : Web application configuration, using profiles: swagger
2017-07-31 13:50:30.801 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] net.amfibia.colony.config.WebConfigurer  : Initializing Metrics registries
2017-07-31 13:50:30.804 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] net.amfibia.colony.config.WebConfigurer  : Registering Metrics Filter
2017-07-31 13:50:30.805 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] net.amfibia.colony.config.WebConfigurer  : Registering Metrics Servlet
2017-07-31 13:50:30.808  INFO 6678 --- [  restartedMain] net.amfibia.colony.config.WebConfigurer  : Web application fully configured
2017-07-31 13:50:31.133 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] n.a.colony.config.DatabaseConfiguration  : Configuring Liquibase
2017-07-31 13:50:31.141  WARN 6678 --- [lony-Executor-1] i.g.j.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase   : Starting Liquibase asynchronously, your database might not be ready at startup!
2017-07-31 13:50:37.037 DEBUG 6678 --- [lony-Executor-1] i.g.j.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase   : Liquibase has updated your database in 5895 ms
2017-07-31 13:50:37.037  WARN 6678 --- [lony-Executor-1] i.g.j.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase   : Warning, Liquibase took more than 5 seconds to start up!
2017-07-31 13:50:37.553 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] n.a.c.config.social.SocialConfiguration  : Configuring GoogleConnectionFactory
2017-07-31 13:50:37.559 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] n.a.c.config.social.SocialConfiguration  : Configuring FacebookConnectionFactory
2017-07-31 13:50:37.561 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] n.a.c.config.social.SocialConfiguration  : Configuring TwitterConnectionFactory
2017-07-31 13:50:37.988  WARN 6678 --- [  restartedMain] c.r.metrics.spring.AnnotationFilter      : Ignoring @Timed on method net.amfibia.colony.web.rest.ColonyResource.updateInitialBalances due to illegal modifiers: private
2017-07-31 13:50:39.246  INFO 6678 --- [  restartedMain] org.elasticsearch.node                   : [Midnight] version[2.4.5], pid[6678], build[c849dd1/2017-04-24T16:18:17Z]
2017-07-31 13:50:39.246  INFO 6678 --- [  restartedMain] org.elasticsearch.node                   : [Midnight] initializing ...
2017-07-31 13:50:39.246 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] org.elasticsearch.node                   : [Midnight] using config [/home/amfibia/projects/colony/config], data [[/home/amfibia/projects/colony/data]], logs [/home/amfibia/projects/colony/logs], plugins [/home/amfibia/projects/colony/plugins]
2017-07-31 13:50:39.250 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] org.elasticsearch.plugins                : [/home/amfibia/projects/colony/plugins] directory does not exist.
2017-07-31 13:50:39.251  INFO 6678 --- [  restartedMain] org.elasticsearch.plugins                : [Midnight] modules [], plugins [], sites []
2017-07-31 13:50:39.275 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] org.elasticsearch.env                    : [Midnight] using node location [[NodePath{path=/home/amfibia/projects/colony/data/elasticsearch/nodes/0, spins=false}]], local_node_id [0]
2017-07-31 13:50:39.279 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] org.elasticsearch.env                    : [Midnight] node data locations details:
 -> /home/amfibia/projects/colony/data/elasticsearch/nodes/0, free_space [14.3gb], usable_space [6.6gb], total_space [151.2gb], spins? [no], mount [/ (/dev/sda5)], type [ext4]
2017-07-31 13:50:39.280  INFO 6678 --- [  restartedMain] org.elasticsearch.env                    : [Midnight] heap size [3.4gb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
2017-07-31 13:50:39.281  WARN 6678 --- [  restartedMain] org.elasticsearch.env                    : [Midnight] max file descriptors [4096] for elasticsearch process likely too low, consider increasing to at least [65536]
2017-07-31 13:50:39.293 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] org.elasticsearch.threadpool             : [Midnight] creating thread_pool [force_merge], type [fixed], size [1], queue_size [null]
2017-07-31 13:50:39.307 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] org.elasticsearch.threadpool             : [Midnight] creating thread_pool [percolate], type [fixed], size [8], queue_size [1k]
2017-07-31 13:50:39.320 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] org.elasticsearch.threadpool             : [Midnight] creating thread_pool [fetch_shard_started], type [scaling], min [1], size [16], keep_alive [5m]
2017-07-31 13:50:39.321 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] org.elasticsearch.threadpool             : [Midnight] creating thread_pool [listener], type [fixed], size [4], queue_size [null]
2017-07-31 13:50:39.322 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] org.elasticsearch.threadpool             : [Midnight] creating thread_pool [index], type [fixed], size [8], queue_size [200]
2017-07-31 13:50:39.322 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] org.elasticsearch.threadpool             : [Midnight] creating thread_pool [refresh], type [scaling], min [1], size [4], keep_alive [5m]
2017-07-31 13:50:39.322 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] org.elasticsearch.threadpool             : [Midnight] creating thread_pool [suggest], type [fixed], size [8], queue_size [1k]
2017-07-31 13:50:39.322 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] org.elasticsearch.threadpool             : [Midnight] creating thread_pool [generic], type [cached], keep_alive [30s]
2017-07-31 13:50:39.323 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] org.elasticsearch.threadpool             : [Midnight] creating thread_pool [warmer], type [scaling], min [1], size [4], keep_alive [5m]
2017-07-31 13:50:39.323 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] org.elasticsearch.threadpool             : [Midnight] creating thread_pool [search], type [fixed], size [13], queue_size [1k]
2017-07-31 13:50:39.323 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] org.elasticsearch.threadpool             : [Midnight] creating thread_pool [flush], type [scaling], min [1], size [4], keep_alive [5m]
2017-07-31 13:50:39.324 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] org.elasticsearch.threadpool             : [Midnight] creating thread_pool [fetch_shard_store], type [scaling], min [1], size [16], keep_alive [5m]
2017-07-31 13:50:39.324 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] org.elasticsearch.threadpool             : [Midnight] creating thread_pool [management], type [scaling], min [1], size [5], keep_alive [5m]
2017-07-31 13:50:39.324 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] org.elasticsearch.threadpool             : [Midnight] creating thread_pool [get], type [fixed], size [8], queue_size [1k]
2017-07-31 13:50:39.324 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] org.elasticsearch.threadpool             : [Midnight] creating thread_pool [bulk], type [fixed], size [8], queue_size [50]
2017-07-31 13:50:39.325 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] org.elasticsearch.threadpool             : [Midnight] creating thread_pool [snapshot], type [scaling], min [1], size [4], keep_alive [5m]
2017-07-31 13:50:39.721 DEBUG 6678 --- [  restartedMain] org.elasticsearch.script                 : [Midnight] failed to load mustache

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.github.mustachejava.Mustache
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at org.elasticsearch.script.ScriptModule.configure(ScriptModule.java:80)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:60)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:233)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:105)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:143)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorBuilder.build(InjectorBuilder.java:99)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:93)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:70)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ModulesBuilder.createInjector(ModulesBuilder.java:46)
        at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:213)
```

Comment: I fixed it now. My mistake. Some errors in the constructors was fixed, and cyclic dependencies -  everything is fine now.